# I want to write a bot for my discord channel to send users "hi" message, who writes hello. But I get error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, auto

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(931570478915657790)
    if channel.content == "hello":
        await channel.send("hi!")
```

When I write this code, i get this error: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'content'

I want to write a bot for my discord channel to send users "hi" message, who writes hello.

Comment: Do you mean `message.content`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `channel.content` you should use `message.content`.
So your code would look something like

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
channel = bot.get_channel(931570478915657790)
if message.content == "hello":
    await channel.send("hi!")
```